# Copy FOLDER from Jenkins workspace folder of a job to another folder and make it readable to everyone with the link WITHOUT ACCESS TO THE WORKSPACE

Tags: jenkins

I have set up jenkins with Maven and git on Windows. My run creates a folder called 'logs' inside workspace of that job  which stores the logs for failed cases ... I DO NOT want to expose workspace folder to others but want the 'logs' folder to be accessible .. Could you please guide me HOW and WHERE in jenkins can I copy the folder so its accessible when the link is shared.
I'd rather delete the workspace folder after the build so that the test source code is not visible.

I tried  to create a dir  outside workspace in BUILD POST STEPS using

```
mkdir ../jobs/Logs 
copy  ./ws/logs ( or logs )  ../jobs/Logs
```

but it still creates a folder within the workspace

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using the archiveArtifacts plugin. I'd zip up your logs and then archive them with the job run. You'll then be able to download the logs through the Jenkins UI. If you want to restrict access, implement the RBAC plugin to protect your jobs.

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/

Comment: Thanks @Derek Williams ..I'm not using pipelines but I used the File Operation plugin to zip the folder and archive artifacts  in Post build action